# How to handle Android app receive Multiple fcm data message?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Send data message for app notification via FCM.

I have various FCM data types, and each type has its own action separate way.

Everything works fine, if I send only one message. App could handle exactly what I want.

But send FCM more than twice, (for example, [FCM - data for action 1] then [FCM - data for action 2] ) something goes wrong.

First, I want to show it separately, but second one overlay the first one.

Second, set 'First question' aside, after I click the message that contains the second one, it works for [ action 1 ] that the first one aimed.

So... I want to solve these problems. Or at least one. ( if first one is solved, second solve naturally )

Thx in advance.

Comment: can u help me How U managed different fcm notifications in android

Comment: @LahariAreti Hello. Sorry for late check. Then what do you aim to now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

did you use NotificationManager for displaying the notifications?

Then try this

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify((int) System.currentTimeMillis(), notifBuilder.build());
```

see the

```
(int) System.currentTimeMillis()
```

that's how i make the unique id for each notifications.

Hope that helps, thanks

Comment: i'll try and get some success. I can display notification separately.
But still cannot execute its own action. 
I think its because of making new same intent object every time, so should i also make intent separately  ?

Comment: Oh, i solved it. Just replace pending intent ID likes notification ID. Thx!

Comment: @JungHoon can u explain how you solved the issue of overlapping?

Comment: @SNos sorry for late replying. are you finished ur issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you want notification seperate, you need define diffrent id for notificaton:

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(<Unique notification id here>, notifBuilder.build());
```

Comment: Thank you too. 
As i mentioned it above, how can i handle its own action ?

Comment: please post ur code in update question, which implement notifBulder

Comment: Thank you for caring my question. Now i solve my question ! 
for using unique id at notifymanager and pending intent!